# Error in running FLASK on anaconda Prompt

Tags: flask, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, command-prompt, ml

I want to start the flask server using anaconda Prompt.
while starting,it is showing the following error.How to resolve error.
 I am getting the following error.

- Environment: production
  WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.

  - Debug mode: off
    Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you need to set flask's debug mode to true.

```
set FLASK_APP = yourfilename.py
set FLASK_DEBUG = 1
```

and then use:

```
flask run
```

to run your server.

Note: If you are on mac/linux use export instead of set

Answer (score 1):

Have you used:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=yourfilename.py

$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1

$ flask run
```